# Problems to convert date to timestamp, Spark date to timestamp from unix_timestamp return null

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, null, unix-timestamp

Problems to convert date to timestamp, Spark date to timestamp from unix_timestamp return null.

```
scala>  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp
scala> spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(('2017-08-13 00:06:05'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS date").show(false)

+----+
|date|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Comment: I tried your code on Spark 2.2 and it works as expected. What version are you using?

Comment: Spark 2.3.1 with Scala 2.11.8. The problem only occurs with dates of month 08 and day 13 or 14, the others work well

Comment: Is your system running in Chile time zone by any chance? Summer time (DST) began in Chile on August 13, 2017. The clocks were turned forward from 00:00 to 01:00, so there *was* no 00:06:05 that night.

Comment: Thanks you Ole V.V. the problem: 13-08-2017 00:01:07|     null  \n 14-08-2016 00:28:42|     null. 
It coincides with the time change.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the change of time in Chile, thank you very much.

```
+-------------------+---------+
|     DateIntermedia|TimeStamp|
+-------------------+---------+
|13-08-2017 00:01:07|     null|
|13-08-2017 00:10:33|     null|
|14-08-2016 00:28:42|     null|
|13-08-2017 00:04:43|     null|
|13-08-2017 00:33:51|     null|
|14-08-2016 00:28:08|     null|
|14-08-2016 00:15:34|     null|
|14-08-2016 00:21:04|     null|
|13-08-2017 00:34:13|     null|
+-------------------+---------+
```

The solution, set timeZone:

```
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC-6")
```